# How to (properly) transition from startManagingCursor to CursorLoader?

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I updated my android `SDK` to the latest version, and now it says that `startManagingCursor()` is `deprecated`. I need help to update my code to use the new  `CursorLoader`.

```
private void fillData() {
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);
    NoteAdapter notes = new NoteAdapter(this,  R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

So, `startManagingCursor()` is old, what would the new code look like, if it was translated?

Comment: CursorLoader works in adition to ContentProvider ... So it is not possible to "translate" rhis code ....

Comment: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html

Comment: Good to keep in mind this answer to the depreciated method. Turns out it runs on the main thread, which slows things down, that's why it was depreciated. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651680/cursorloader-with-startmanagingcursor)

Answer (score 16):

First, `startManagingCursor()` still works. It is not ideal, in that it performs database I/O on the main application thread. In Android, "deprecated" generally means "we have something else that we think is better that we suggest you use". So, when it makes sense in the development cycle of your app, you should consider migrating.

Second, as Selvin noted, the SDK only provides a `Loader` implementation for a `ContentProvider`. I have [a project that offers a `Loader` for SQLite](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex) directly.

Third, there really is no straight-up "translation" for your code. The `Loader` framework is asynchronous and event-driven, whereas your code is not.

Generally speaking, your `Loader` would be responsible for fetching the notes, and you would populate your `ListView` in `onLoadFinished()`, when you are delivered the `Cursor` from the `Loader`.

Comment: Just to add a thought here, if you are building NEW code you should never use deprecated API's.

Comment: @EthanAllen: Nonsense. For starters, it's impossible if you want to support older devices. For example, you cannot create a `PreferenceActivity` that works on API Level 10 and below without using deprecated methods. Deprecation warnings need to be considered on a case-by-case basis. *Generally* you want to avoid deprecated methods where possible. But "never" is overstating the case.