# rewriting a method to use cursor loader

Tags: java, android, sql, cursor

I have a method to display note title and date from a database. However method `startManagingCursor` is deprecated. Is there any way I can re-write this using cursor loader ?

```
private void fillData() {
    // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);


    String[] from = new String[] { NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE ,NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DATE};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 ,R.id.date_row};

    // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145735/how-to-properly-transition-from-startmanagingcursor-to-cursorloader

Answer (score 0):

The regular CursorLoader is based on Android's ContentProvider - so if you're not using it, you'll have to write your own Loader. Here's one way you can do it:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex/blob/master/src/com/commonsware/cwac/loaderex/acl/AbstractCursorLoader.java

From that point it's pretty straight forward. 
Your activity/fragment can be a callback for the LoaderManager - it will need to implement LoaderCallbacks interface.

Instead of running your query, use getLoaderManager().initLoader(this, null, LOADER_ID) to initialize data loading. Here's an example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html

Now, the data will be in the onLoadFinished() callback. If you did everything right, you'll get your cursor here. Now simply use the cursor to populate your list.