# CursorLoader with startManagingCursor()

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I use CursorLoader in my App, to do DB transactions.

My app also has the method calling startManagingCursor(), which is deprecated.

I just want to replace this method calling, so what am I supposed to do ?

Comment: If I don't use this method calling, It will not manage the cursor certainly.

Comment: My app was developed using CursorLoader but without LoadManager.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`startManagingCursor()` is deprecated because it does operations on the main thread which can freeze up the UI and deliver a poor user experience. You should use a [CusrorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) with a [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) instead. Check out [this tutorial series](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html) from [`Alex Lockwood`](https://plus.google.com/100751609891157863386) for detailed instructions:.

Comment: See an example of using CursorLoader on http://android.codota.com/scenarios/527f77cbda0a05bf241c648b/android.content.CursorLoader?tag=antelope